# Reporting Services - SharePoint 2010 Integrated mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

E-Mail subscriptions couldn't send, all e-mail subscriptions are in "Pending" status. Some e-mails sent but some don't. Is there anybody know anything about it? Why are they all in pending status? How can I display e-mail queue on report server? Is there any tool for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Subscriptions were waiting queue and "Notifications" table is using for queue on report server.